# Add popup in Ag-Grid custom cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Can anyone please help with the problem? I'm trying to add popup to the custom component in Ag-Grid cell. But the popup is not displaying at all.

I'm using bootstrap popup modal also tried with bootstrap popover, but nothing seems to be working.

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit, ICellRendererAngularComp {
  activeValue:any;
  inActive:any
  isOpen:boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams<any, any>): void {
    this.activeValue = params.data.City;
    this.inActive = params.data.City;
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams<any, any>): boolean {
    return true;
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="activeValue == 'Bangalore' else inActive">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <img src="../../assets/water-drop.png" alt="">
        <span class="badge badge-dark">2</span>
    </button>
</div>

<ng-template #inActive>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary " disabled>
            <img src="../../assets/water-drop.png" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onCellClicked` like this:

**html:**

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [editType]="'fullRow'"
  [suppressClickEdit]="true"
  [animateRows]="true"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PopupCellRenderer } from './popup-cell-renderer/popup-cell-renderer.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Action (Angular)',
      colId: 'action',
      cellRenderer: PopupCellRenderer,
      pinned: 'left',
      editable: false,
      maxWidth: 150,
    },
    { field: 'make', editable: true },
    { field: 'model', editable: true },
    { field: 'price', editable: true },
  ];

  rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
  ];

  defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
  };

  onCellClicked(params) {
    if (
      params.event.target.dataset.action == 'toggle' &&
      params.column.getColId() == 'action'
    ) {
      const cellRendererInstances = params.api.getCellRendererInstances({
        rowNodes: [params.node],
        columns: [params.column],
      });
      if (cellRendererInstances.length > 0) {
        const instance = cellRendererInstances[0];
        instance.togglePopup();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can check this working example from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-popup-blog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and you can check this article for more details from [here](https://blog.ag-grid.com/creating-popups-in-ag-grid/)

Comment: I've wrote the whole working example , you can check it if that's what you looking.

Comment: While using bootstrap modal, the modal view is not coming.